# After installing ColdFusion 11, I saw that it a version upgrade (version7) and installed it and the server crashed

Tags: coldfusion

Several months ago I purchased the upgrade to ColdFusion 11 but only now am upgrading it. I uninstalled ColdFusion 10 and installed ColdFusion 11 today and that installed ok. After installing ColdFusion 11, I saw that it a version upgrade (version7) so I told it to install it and that’s when the server crashed with the following error: HTTP Status 500 . I’ve tried it a couple of times with the same issue. Can you help me figure out why it won’t update and also kills ColdFusion? (I’m unable to rollback the install so the ColdFusion server is now kinda dead) I’m installing it on a Dell PE 1950 Server running Win 2008 Server (64bit) w/ 16GB of RAM.

CF11-Windows 2008 64 bit machine

Error Occured :

> HTTP Status 500 - ________________________________________ type Exception report message description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception java.lang.NullPointerException coldfusion.CfmServlet.init(CfmServlet.java:97) coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121) coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I think updates are only Jar files, have you tried removing the Jar?

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling 11?

Comment: "I saw that it a version upgrade (version7)" - do you mean a hotfix? What was the update? Also when you install for the Configure ColdFusion step are you choosing IIS or built-in?